# Find files missing from a folder/subfolder

Tags: find

I have a backup system based on `rsync --link-dest`. I'm trying to optimize disk usage a bit more.

Once in a while, I delete large files in the source folder. What'd be an easy way to automatically search for these files so I can delete them in the backup (if I deem it appropriate) ?

Something like "find files in `/media/backup` that are larger than 100MB and which aren't hardlinked to anything in `/media/backup/latest`"?

Notes:

- There can be 10-20 backup folders in `/media/backup`, named by date. `latest` is a symlink to... you guessed it.
- Files are sometimes moved around and/or renamed, and hardlinks are re-created in thoses cases by occasional checks with `hardlink`. So I'm assuming that the search must be done by inode, not by filename.
- I know that some tools are aware of hardlinks, like `du` - `du /media/backup/*` will only report the *extra* spare used by each backup folder - but I don't know how to leverage this with `find`.

Answer (score 0):

All right... time to program it then.

Here's something that works for my use-case. I'm fully aware that this is crappy code... but posting in case it can help someone else. Performance is better than I expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import os

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("Usage: %s <basepath> <minsize>" % (sys.argv[0],))
size = int(sys.argv[2])

# step 1: find inodes of all large files in most recent backup
inodes = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]+"latest"):
    for name in files:
        file = os.path.join(root, name)
        statinfo = os.stat(file)
        if(statinfo.st_size >= size):
            inodes.append(statinfo.st_ino)

# step 2: find inodes of all large files in all backups, and display if only not in list built in step 1
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for name in files:
        file = os.path.join(root, name)
        statinfo = os.stat(file)
        if(statinfo.st_size >= size):
            try:
                position=inodes.index(statinfo.st_ino)
            except ValueError:
                print("Match: %s (%dMB)" % (file,(statinfo.st_size/(1024*1024)),))
```